# "Contractor" and "Orderer" in a contract about computer software

Tags: word-choice

I'm recently decided to draw up an agreement with an American company and found formal word choice quite challenging. My biggest problem right now is related to naming parties in the agreement. Right now, I refer to the person that develops the software (myself actually) as to the "contractor" and the person who ordered the software as "orderer". Are there any more suitable terms that could be useful in the context of this contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Client** would be a better word, or possibly **client company**, instead of the rather clumsy "orderer".

Answer (score 0):

From my (admittedly limited) experience here, "**Contractor**" for you, and "**Company**" for the company you are going to undertake work for would be the typical terms used to name the parties involved.

FWIW, compare also [Wikipedia's Independent Contractor article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_contractor), and also a [sample contract](http://www.inc.com/tools/2000/12/21529.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could be the "contractor" or "developer" or "provider" and the company could be the "buyer" or "purchaser" or "customer." It is best in the first paragraph to fully identify the parties followed by the word you will use to describe them in the remainder of the document:  John Smith ("Developer") and XYZ Company, Inc., ("Purchaser.")